# Cucumber *.feature and cypress *.cy.ts running in the same repository

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Can I have `*.feature` and `*.cy.ts` tests run in the same repository ?

how should my cypress.config.ts look like?
they get listed in E2E specs with current

```js
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature|cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts',
```

listing both, but all  fails to execute, expected at least the .feature files to execute properly

```js
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature',
```

works fine but still I need to have *.cy.ts listed and executed properly with cypress

```js
e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        const bundler = createBundler({
            plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        });

        on('file:preprocessor', bundler);
        await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

        return config;
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature|cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts',
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `specPattern` option can be an array, so you can try this

```js
specPattern: ['cypress/e2e/**/*.feature', 'cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts'],
```

The logic is applied in an OR pattern.